# function in Backbone is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view in Backbone which has multiple functions.
The functions I have are initialize, render, answer, answerQuestion, nextQuestion.

Here is the code I have in the initialize function

```
initialize: function(game) {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'answer');
    this.render();
}
```

In the render function I call the answerQuestion function by doing this:

```
this.answerQuestion();
```

It works fine.

But in my answer function I call the nextQuestion function the same way and I get this error `undefined is not a function`, if I just call the function without the `this` at the start I get this error `'nextQuestion is not defined'`

What am I missing to get this working.
Here is the full answer function:

```
var v = $('.question.current .type').find('.input').val();

if (v !== undefined) {
    var t = new Date();
    var time_spent = t.getTime() - this.t.getTime();

    var self = this;
    answer.save().done(function(result, status) {
        if (status === 'success') {

            this.nextQuestion();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use your `self` variable?

Comment: @Jack. That was it. Still a bit if a rookie at the mo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're referring to the wrong context with: `this.nextQuestion();`. It should be `self.nextQuestion();`. Or you could bind the callback to the external function's context like this:

```
var v = $('.question.current .type').find('.input').val();

if (v !== undefined) {
    var t = new Date();
    var time_spent = t.getTime() - this.t.getTime();

    var self = this;
    answer.save().done(function(result, status) {
        if (status === 'success') {

            this.nextQuestion();

        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why would this.nextQuestion not work without it being a variable?

Comment: @zizther That's because what `this` refers to changes depending on the `context`. I recommend you read up a bit on JavaScript's context.